# No such file or directory: 'final_data_1.npy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying this code using tensorflow and numpy. However, I am getting an error.

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

np.random.seed(1)

ops.reset_default_graph()
ops.reset_default_graph()

#final_data_1 and 2 are the numpy array files for the images in the folder img and annotations.csv file

#total of 5 GB due to conversion of values to int

Z2= np.load('final_data_1.npy')

Z1= np.load('final_data_2.npy')

print(Z2[:,0])

print(Z1.shape)

my error is:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'final_data_1.npy'
```

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Like the Error message implies you have to name the right directory where this file "final_data_1.npy" is located at:

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("./Path/where/you/stored/table/data.csv")
print(df)
```

Same goes with the function .load()
You have to add the directory of this file

```
np.load('./User/Desktop/final_data_1.npy')
```

Without naming the directory where the file is located your computer doesn't know where "final_data_1" is

Comment: i am tried this way       Z1= np.load("/home/lenovo/Desktop/final_data_1.npy")
Z2= np.save("/home/lenovo/Desktop/final_data_2.npy") but i got same error